# How to combine all sentences to form a continuous flow of text in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, formatting

When I copy and paste Youtube Transcript on MS word, the text appears with sentences on different lines. For example, Instead of " We are celebrating this as a huge occasion in our hometown", it appears as
"We are

celebrating this as

a huge occasion

in our hometown"
in MS word. Is there a better way to combine the text to form full continuous sentences?

Comment: If timestamps are toggled to Off, there shouldn't be any empty lines. Then to join the lines, you can get rid of end-of-lines, but this will make the entire selected text into one paragraph.

Comment: See Word MVP Suzanne Barnhill's article: Cleaning Up Pasted Text http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/CleanWebText.htm

Comment: Ok I received a similar solution from my brother. Copy the same text in Notepad++ . Select the text. Go to edit > line operations > join lines...and then copy the same in word

Answer (score 0):

Use "Find and replace" to remove the paragraph breaks and replace them a space.  You can use the "f" and "r" keys to quickly cycle through and remove them.  Then, use Find and replace to replace a space between two words with period and a space.  Use the "f" and "r" keys to quickly move through to each space.  If the space doesn't require a period, hit "f" again to move to the next until you get to a space which marks the end of a sentence.  When you get to a space that requires the period, select "r" rather than "f" and the space will be replaced with a period and a space.